# Time series classification with noisy labels using cleanlab and sktime

Tags: python, time-series, classification, data-cleaning, sktime

So I want to improve may sktime classifier using cleanlab. Here are some sample data

```
x=np.linspace(0,3,500)
X_true=np.array([randint(1,10)*np.sin(x) for _ in range(100)])
X_false=np.array([randint(1,10)*np.tan(x) for i in range(100)])
y=[True for _ in range (100)]+[False for _ in range (100)]
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_true),pd.DataFrame(X_false)])
df['y']=y
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
X=df.drop('y', axis=1).to_numpy()
y=df['y'].to_numpy()
```

This creates a dataset of time series for sin functions with a label `True` and tan function with label `False`. To create some label errors we set the first 20 targets to True

```
y[:20]=True
```

Now I am using the `sktime` classifier to find the labels for each time series, which is working fine

```
>>> X=from_2d_array_to_nested(X)
>>> clf=TimeSeriesForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1).fit(X,y)
>>> clf.score(X,y)
0.95
```

However, I want to use `cleanlab` to inform the classifier that some of his training labels might not be correct

```
>>> LearningWithNoisyLabels(clf=TimeSeriesForestClassifier()).fit(X,y)
```

But this results in a KeyError

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([  1,   2,   4,   5,   6,   7,  11,  13,  15,  17,\n            ...\n            186, 187, 188, 190, 191, 192, 194, 196, 198, 199],\n           dtype='int64', length=160)] are in the [columns]"
```

Since `LearningWithNoisyLabels` is working for me with other classifiers, I guess there is a problem with the sktime classifier but I am not sure

Version Info:

```
>>> cleanlab.__version__, sktime.__version__
('0.1.1', '0.5.3')
```

Imports:

```
>>> from cleanlab.classification import LearningWithNoisyLabels
>>> from sktime.utils.data_processing import from_2d_array_to_nested
>>> from sktime.classification.all import TimeSeriesForestClassifier
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that during `LearningWithNoisyLabels(..).fit()` the function `cleanlab.latent_estimation.estimate_confident_joint_and_cv_pred_proba` is throwing an exception since it does not handle the sktime feature format correctly. The result of `from_2d_array_to_nested()` is a `pd.DataFrame` with 1 column and a `pd.Series`in each cell.

However, if we define the `TimeSeriesForestClassifier` inside a pipeline that takes a normal `np.array` as input everything is working fine.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

clf=make_pipeline(FunctionTransformer(from_2d_array_to_nested),
                  TimeSeriesForestClassifier())
clf_clean=LearningWithNoisyLabels(clf)
clf_clean.fit(X,y)
```